# Firefox Currently used plugin detection with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, pdf

My problem is as follows, I have a page within my application that uses submit form PDF's, which experience the same issues as XFA forms (that is, they don't work correctly - more info about that issue here: http://helpx.adobe.com/livecycle/kb/xfa-forms-firefox-chrome.html).  This works fine within IE, and I have code to properly detect the plugins in Chrome as well:

```
  $.each(navigator.plugins, function () {
            var pluginname = this.name;
            var isValid = false;
            var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
             if (pluginname.indexOf('Chrome PDF Viewer') > -1) {
              alert('You appear to be using the default PDF viewer for Chrome.  This has known issues with this page.  Please either use Internet Explorer, or see http://helpx.adobe.com/livecycle/kb/xfa-forms-firefox-chrome.html for instructions on how to change your default PDF viewer.');
             }
        });
```

This works fine for Chrome, however I can't use the same sort of check for Firefox, as Chrome actually hides the plugin from the list if disabled, whereas Firefox does not.  Does anyone know of a way to check if a plugin is actually active in Firefox?  As is tagged, the application is an asp.net/vb.net application, so even if this has to be done on the server side, that's fine.